# How to add impulsive and gamma noise to an image without using imnoise function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, noise

I was wondering if you could give me some advice on how to add impulsive and Gamma noise to an image separately? It's so easy with imnoise function of matlab, but i'm not allowed to use imnoise, Our TA said you can just use rand function.

I came across this code but it seems it doesn't work as it should(for impulse noise):

```
    noisyimage=originalimage+255*rand(size(originalimage));
```

Comment: That will add white noise to your image, but it assumes your image is uint8 where yours might be double. if it's double just drop the 255.

Comment: @Dan thanks buddy, it worked..but what about Gamma noise? i couldn't find its code on the web :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with that line of code:

- `255*rand()` generates double-valued numbers, whereas your image will probably be of type `uint8` or so (check with `class(originalimage)`). To fix, use `randi` for instance:

  ```
  noisyimage = randi(255, size(originalimage), class(originalimage));
  ```

  (use `intmax(class(originalimage))` to be completely generic)
- you add noise of maximum magnitude 255 to *all* pixels. This might overflow many of your pixels (that is, get assigned values higher than 255). To avoid, use something like

  ```
  noisyimage = min(255, originalimage + randi(...) );
  ```
- The noise direction is only *positive*. True noise also sometimes brings *down* the values of the pixels. So, use something like

  ```
  noisyimage = max(0, min(255, originalimage + randi(...)-127 );
  ```
- the maximum amplitude of 255 is actually **way** too big; you'll likely destroy your whole image and only get noise. Try a few different amplitudes, `A`, like so:

  ```
  noisyimage = max(0, min(255, originalimage + randi(A, ...)-round(A/2) );
  ```
- The uniform distribution which `randi` uses is not a really good source of noise; you'd want some other distribution. Use the normal distribution:

  ```
  uint8(A*randn(...)-round(A/2))
  ```

  or gamma:

  ```
  uint8(A*randg(...)-round(A/2))
  ```

  etc.

Now, that should get you started :)

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks for your help, But i still cannot figure it out how to add Gamma noise to a RGB image

Comment: @rody For your first point, I am wondering if '3' is necessary? Because for a RGB image `size` already returns something like 1500 * 2000 * 3. Isn't it?